# Angular doesn't bind repeater after first push to array

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular repeater bound to an array. When I push a new item, the UI updates as expected, but for subsequent pushes, the array updates but the UI doesn't change. I already tried `scope.$apply()` but it doesn't make any difference.

```
var app = angular.module('m', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.maxValue = 6;
    $scope.values = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

    $scope.update = function (){
        $scope.maxValue++
        $scope.values.push($scope.maxValue);
        //$scope.$apply();
    }
});
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. [Here's a small example that replicates the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/ukk3362m/5/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are pussing the same value again and again which creates duplicate elements, try using **`track by index`**

```
 <li data-ng-repeat="item in values track by $index">
```

[`working fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/ukk3362m/4/)

Comment: ng-repeat doesn't allow duplicates by default? In my real app (not this example) I am actually pushing an object, which is different each time, so I don't understand why it would not work. Does it track by some default property like "id"?

Comment: no it does not allow duplcates, btw you are pussing a string not an object